# Joining two tables but with select requiring all secondary columns to be the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a select statement to output only if all columns in a table selection have the same value for a given key in a second table.

Here's the example:

The table ‘Rule’ below has the same values (name, age) for each ruleid. However, ‘state’ value changes with each row (True/False) in ‘Rule’ table.

I want to be able to select from table ‘Rule’ where the ruleid from table ‘Hash’ is equal to the ‘ruleid’ in table ‘Rule’ and ONLY write to output if **all the selected ‘state’ values** with that ‘ruleid’ from ‘Hash’ are equal to the ‘state’ value for that ruleid in table ‘Hash’.

Here’s what the example output should look like:

```
ruleid    name    age  col2
27488     Bob     99    xx              // output because all the rows In Table Rule with ruleid=27488 have state=False
27455     Sue     23    xx              // output because all the rows in Table Rule with ruleid=27455 have state=True
27444     Tim     34    xx              // output because all the rows in Table Rule with ruleid=27444 have state=False
```

The example table ‘Hash’ below has a row with ruleid 27460 has state = 'True'.  The table ‘Rule’ (following) has rows with both that same ‘ruleid’ and ‘state’ values with **except for one row** - so no output. 
If all the rows in ‘Rule’ for that ‘ruleid’ had the same value for ‘state’ as in Hash then output should be one line for that ‘ruleid’ row.

Hash

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| ruleid      | state        | colx       | col2  | 
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| 27488       | False        | XXX        | XX    |
| 27455       | True         | XXX        | XX    |
| 27460       | True         | XXX        | XX    |
| 27444       | False        | XXX        | XX    |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

Rule

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| ruleid      | state        | name       | age   | 
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| 27488       | False        | Bob        | 99    |
| 27488       | False        | Bob        | 99    |
| 27460       | True         | Randy      | 11    |
| 27460       | True         | Randy      | 11    |
| 27460       | False        | Randy      | 11    |
| 27455       | True         | Sue        | 23    |
| 27455       | True         | Sue        | 23    |
| 27455       | True         | Sue        | 23    |
| 27444       | False        | Tim        | 34    |
| 27444       | False        | Tim        | 34    |
| 27444       | False        | Tim        | 34    |
| 27444       | False        | Tim        | 34    |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: this is a normal JOIN.  what sql have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct r.ruleid,
                r.name,
                r.age,
                h.col2 
from hash h
join rule r on r.ruleId = h.ruleId
where not exists
( 
select 1 
from rule rr 
where rr.ruleId = h.ruleId
  and rr.state <>  h.state
)
```

Comment: You are missing few things correct those as here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/277728/2. Need to do a group by. Never the less +1

Comment: As @AbhikChakraborty said, or use a `distinct` in the select as here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b72ea/3/0

Comment: That would be a solution for having only 1 record back, I wasn't sure if the user wanted all the records returned.

Comment: Looking for one record back per row in table 'Hash' that meets the select criteria in table 'Rule'.  Does the above do that?

Comment: It should output multiple records like the example output above